# How to solve the error "Oops! That page can’t be found" when access Portfolio

Tags: errors

My website is being on https://ahamedia.vn.
It shows the error "Oops! That page can’t be found" when access any Portfolio item at this links: https://ahamedia.vn/hau-truong/

Describe:
I use 2 plugins about Portfolio:

- 1 portfolio is available when installing WP;
- 1 piece using Visual Portfolio plugin.
  Objects using Visual Portfolio are normally displayed

Please suggest a solution to this error!
Thanks

Comment: Did you try to visit the settings/permalinks section in the wp-admin - this will flush the rewrite rules and might help?

Comment: Thanks. It's OK when changing to option Default (https://ahamedia.vn/?p=123) in Settings/Permalinks. After that, changing back to option Custom Structure (https://ahamedia.vn//%postname%/), it gets that error again.
I still want to leave the path containing the title of the posts for better SEO

Answer (score 0):

Try with reset permalink from WordPress setting and revisit the portfolio page. If you are using any cache plugin then don't forgot to clear the cache.

Comment: Thanks. 
In Setting \ Permalinks: I am setting the option Custom Structure (ahamedia.vn//%postname%). 
It's OK when changing to option Default (ahamedia.vn/?p=123). After that, changing back to option Custom Structure (ahamedia.vn//%postname%), it gets that error again. I still want to leave the links containing the title of the posts for better SEO.